# Align text under CSS sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites, text-alignment

I have a number of links, each have a class passing the correct sprite to present each image and the relative hover image for each link.

The problem is aligning the text directly underneath the sprite.

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

My problem specific code:

```
.image_row td a{
    background-image:url('http://www.thechefsdirectory.com/images/navigation/VIEW_WEB.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

.image_row td a.item1 {background-position:0px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item1 {background-position:0px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item2 {background-position:-70px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item2 {background-position:-70px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item3 {background-position:-140px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item3 {background-position:-140px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item4 {background-position:-210px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item4 {background-position:-210px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item5 {background-position:-280px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item5 {background-position:-280px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item6 {background-position:-350px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item6 {background-position:-350px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item7 {background-position:-420px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item7 {background-position:-420px -70px;}

.image_row td a.item8 {background-position:-490px 0px;}
.image_row td a:hover.item8 {background-position:-490px -70px;}
```

The related JSFIDDLE can be found [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/53uLN/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this one will look weird, but...

```
.image_row td a{
    background-image:url('http://www.thechefsdirectory.com/images/navigation/VIEW_WEB.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 70px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
    width: 70px;
}
```

zero `height` and 70px `padding-top`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/53uLN/1/

Comment: thanks for that, but do you know the reason why it works like this?

Comment: @Chris The `padding` is added to the width/height so you now actually have a 70x70px box but with no space for content, so the content is pushed outside of the boundaries of the block, but it is still visible because the default value for `overflow` is `visible`, if you set it to `hidden` it will disappear.